# In 13.10 "unlock from launcher" option isn't working

Tags: unity, launcher, 13.10

I'm quite new here in Ubuntu and I've updated from 13.04 to 13.10 yesterday and I've noticed that when I install new applications from software center it stays in the unity launcher and I can't remove "like in 13.04" by pressing "right click" and then "Don't stay in launcher". This option is not working.

Could you please let me know how can I remove unwanted applications in the launcher?

I've restarted more than 2 times without luck.

Answer (score 5):

This post over at bugs.lauchpad.net worked perfect for me:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1233199/comments/6

The above post suggests deleting the cache database:

```
cd ~/.local/share/zeitgeist
rm activity.sqlite
```

or you could back it up, if you may want to recover anything:

```
mv activity.sqlite activity.sqlite.bak
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! While this may be helpful, it would be better to include the information in the answer itself.

Comment: worked also for me!

Answer (score 1):

I recently upgraded my 12.04 to 14.04 and I wasn't able to remove anything from the launcher.
The solution for me was to change the security settings of `~/.local/share/zeitgeist/activity.sqlite`
to allow myself to read and write.